# Toshiba USB HDD crashes RPi 5 when doing cp or mv ; Works fine on other machine

Tags: usb, crash

I have several disk drives plugged into a USB hub. They all work fine, except the Toshiba 1TB HDD drive, which did work OK with my RPi 4. I accidentally ran out of space on the drive and since then the problem started.
When I try to copy or move files from it when it is connected to the RPi 5 it crashes the Pi5, however I can plug it into my Chromebook and move files from it to other disk drives plugged into the Pi5's USB hub shared over my LAN without problems.

I have looked through the journal but I cannot see any relevant messages.

Please can anyone suggest a solution, or tell me why it is happening, or at least where to look for error messages that will point me in the right direction?
Could the fact that I maxed it out by accident be related in any way?
It is 96% full now.

Comment: Enough power supplied?

Comment: Yes I believe so. I am using the recommended PSU and the drives are plugged into a powered USB hub. Only the Toshiba one is doing this.

Comment: Perhaps you need to repair the file system on another computer.

Comment: Well, I guess is when your disk a almost full, and you try to do copy or move file operation which would need a temp/swap space. The OS would not first check if there is enough space for swapping, and just take the risk/gamble, hoping that all would be well, ... I learnt this subtle trap years ago when playing with OSes, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it was a power issue probably.

I plugged the drive into another USB socket on the Pi5 and unmounted a couple of drives that were plugged into the USB hub.

The problem has gone.

Comment: Your hub needs enough power too. Consider upgrading.

Comment: Yes, I underestimated the power requirements